# Exit sequence in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, logout

I have Stepping Load Thread Group which is creating 50 users. I do login once for each user and then I repeat some actions for 1 hour. I have specified in Stepping Load Thread Group to hold load for one hour. I want each user to do logout at the end. I know this is not directly implemented in Jmeter, but I hope you can give me some advice how to build this with other Jmeter components. Thanks

Comment: guys please anybody :(? this is important?my angry boss is getting more angry :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `Run time controller` for your requirement?

```
Thread Group
   Login
   Run Time controller (for 1 hour)
       - Your repeatable actions
   Logout
```